# popup div like http://www.kelkoo.co.uk/

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

go to http://www.kelkoo.co.uk/ and click on the down arrow of the category link a popup div will appear ...i need similar kind of pop up div.the data will be loaded dynamically and in the time of loading a loading image will also appear in the middle of div.

plz see these image

[loading image](http://picasaweb.google.com/ks.it2003/Public#5416537947568789362)

[loaded image](http://picasaweb.google.com/ks.it2003/Public#5416537952240886498)

N.B plz notice if i click for 2nd time the loading image does not appear plz help me to achieve similar kind of functionality

Comment: Umm you should first try it yourself. When you are halfway there and get stuck you can come back and post. Nobody is going to do all the work for you. For such a thing better check rentacoder.com or similar sites

Comment: thnx for you valuable comment

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily create such overlay using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and jQuery addon called [Ajaxify](http://maxblog.me/ajaxify/).

Comment: i am a beginner plz provide sample application link if u have.

Comment: There are several demo scripts in "Demo" section of Ajaxify webpage. But perhaps you should just study some javascript/AJAX basics first, so you can implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Ajaxify-plugin suggested by ondrowan is a good option.

The reason the load-image is not shown the second time is that the results are cached -> no need for reload.

I'm not really sure of the accuracy of the answer you're looking for, so please spesify the question if you want more details..

Comment: look those image and just  go to the site u will understand the requirement